# How to fix error Cannot GET with Node.js / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a class Server :
Server.js

```
const express = require('express');

class Server {
    constructor() {
        this.app = express();

        this.app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            res.send('Hello World');
        })
    }

    start() {
        this.app.listen(8080, function() {
            console.log('MPS application is listening on port 8080 !')
        });
    }
}
module.exports = Server;
```

I start my server in app.js :

```
const Server = require('./server/Server');
const express = require('express');

const server = new Server();

server.start();

server.app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

My html code :
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="historique">
        <button v-on:click="openHistorique">
            Historique Proface
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.js :

```
window.onload = function () {   
    var hist = new Vue({
        el:'#historique',
        methods: {
            openHistorique: function() {
                console.log("On clique");
                document.location.href="../AffichageHistorique/index.php";
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And the folder structure :

```
client
  AffichageHistorique
    index.php
  js
    index.js
  index.html
server
  Server.js
app.js
```

When I click on the button in index.html, I want to open index.php but i have the error `Cannot GET /AffichageHistorique/index.php` and I don't see how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

> ```
> this.app.get('/', function(req, res) {
> ```

… you wrote a handler for what happens when the client tries to get `/`.

You haven't written one for `/AffichageHistorique/index.php`.

> ```
> server.app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
> ```

… comes close, but since your URL doesn't start with `/client`, it doesn't get hit.

Even if it did, it wouldn't **execute** the PHP.

The static module is for serving **static** files, not for executing PHP.

If you're using PHP, then consider using a server that PHP is designed to work with (like Apache HTTPD or Lighttpd).

Comment: But with code 
```
server.app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
server.app.use('/client/AffichageHistorique', express.static(__dirname + '/client/AffichageHistorique'));
```
in app.js it must work fine no?

Comment: @MissKnacki — No. Your URL doesn't start with `/client`

Comment: Yes indeed, I didn"t notice, thank you ! And Iwill change my code to not use php anymore, It will be better I think